# My script always do its default case

Tags: php

I made this script and it only does the default case even if I change the contents of config.yml

```
<?php 
    $myfile = fopen("config.yml", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("config.yml"));
    $content = fread($myfile,filesize("config.yml"));
    switch ($content) {
        case "1":
            echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href ="office365/index.html";'; 
            echo '</script>';
        case "2":
            echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href ="connection_reset/index.html";'; 
            echo '</script>';
        case "3":
            echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href ="minimal/index.html";'; 
            echo '</script>';
        default:
            echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href ="noconfigured.html";'; 
            echo '</script>';
    }
    fclose($myfile);
    ?>
```

My config.yml contents:
1

If you have any ideas please help.

Comment: RTFM >>> http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I just want you to know that [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is a think you can use.

Comment: Dont worry about the downvote. There are a lot of people here with an elitist attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so people can have the working version of the code above :

```
<?php 
    $myfile = fopen("config.yml", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("config.yml"));
    $content =  file_get_contents("config.yml");
    switch ($content) {
        case "1":
            echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href ="office365/index.html";'; 
            echo '</script>';
        break;
        case "2":
            echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href ="connection_reset/index.html";'; 
            echo '</script>';
        break;
        case "3":
            echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href ="minimal/index.html";'; 
            echo '</script>';
        break;
        default:
            echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href ="noconfigured.html";'; 
            echo '</script>';
        break;
    }
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not using break in each case, the echo value will be set to the default value:

```
echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'window.location.href ="noconfigured.html";'; 
echo '</script>';
```

In order to fix this just add a break statement after each case:

```
    case "1":
        echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href ="office365/index.html";'; 
        echo '</script>';
    break;
    case "2":
        echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href ="connection_reset/index.html";'; 
        echo '</script>';
    break;
    case "3":
        echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href ="minimal/index.html";'; 
        echo '</script>';
    break;
    default:
        echo '<script script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href ="noconfigured.html";'; 
        echo '</script>';
    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

I just forgot breaks and i used file_get_contents() to do it.